# Buttons for new panes in tmux

Tags: tmux, tmux-plugin-manager

I find `Ctrl+b "` and `Ctrl+b x` to be difficult to press quickly. I know you can change the prefix to something else, and rebind keys.

However I'd ideally like buttons that allow me to create new panes and close them. This would work well with the mouse mode I'm already using to resize and switch to panes. Is there a tmux plugin that would give me buttons like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build tmux from master or 3.0 and then use the menus. If you have mouse on, then you can right click on a pane to split it or kill it (or Meta + right click if it is copy mode or running an application that uses the mouse):

[image]

If you don't like the default menus then you can customize them by changing the key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, perhaps you are talking about mouse buttons - you can bind the mouse buttons to anything you like, for example:

```
bind -n M-DoubleClick1 split-window
```

Will make Meta + double click split the pane.

Comment: No I was talking about buttons inside tmux itself, as in your first answer. I am trying to build tmux from source now although I'm having difficult, I will accept your answer once I can get it to work!

Comment: What is the difficulty? tmux should be pretty easy to build.

Comment: `At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
make: *** [control.o] Error 1` when I execute `make`

Comment: That is a warning, what is the error message? Are you trying to use libevent 1.4? What platform are you on?

Comment: Yes I have installed  libevent-1.4.13 and libevent-devel. I'm on redhat linux

Comment: 1.4.13 is very old, you can use it but you need to open tmux's control.c and comment out line 79 that says evbuffer_readln - just put a // at the start, then it should build.

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Comment: Great just note that with this line commented out control mode won't work, but unless you are using the tmux integration in iTerm2 on OS X you won't need it.